# print ViewRoot as jsf file (showing the tags)

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, viewroot

From ViewRoot how can I print or get the jsf markup? I mean, I have the original jsf file, then using a bean I change many properties. How can I print this new state of the jsf file? I believe is using ViewRoot but how? I know I can print the object tree as java objects but I`m looking to get back as jsf file with its tags.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. But why would you want to? First time in 10 years I hear this requirement

Comment: @Kukeltje Many things are added through the bean. That`s how it works. At some point is so complex that is valuable to have this chance to look with the tags as a normal page.

Comment: Why not do it the other way around? Manipulate the xhtml and then you, well, have the xhtml

Comment: @Kukeltje I can`t. I have many complex ViewRoot where I don`t have the jsf file. I believe this or something near to this is available in the jsf itself. At some point it reads the tags and creates the java objects, so giving the java objects we could get the tags back.

Comment: And I know for sure there is not such a thing. Never heard of it nor problems with it in 15 years. Having a parser that reads the tags an creates java objects does not automagically mean the reverse is available too. I know, I've built them, not for jsf but for a custom view technology used in combination with flash/flex. But then again, I'm not all-knowing, like BalusC, so I might be wrong.

Comment: Any idea of how I could achieve this? In jsf code do you know where the tags are turned into java objects and then into html markup? Thanks